# MS-Access (2007) updating one (or two) related tables from another table/query

Tags: ms-access-2007

[image]

`Query1` contains the records I would like to insert in the related tables `Categorie` and `Sub_Categorie`. How do I do that. 
This is MS-ACCESS 2007.

I would like to update the `categorie`. `categorie` from `query1.cat` (only if there is a new category to be inserted).  The `query1.s_cat` and `query1.label` need to be inserted into the subcategory table If that combination, label & subcategory is new to the corresponding category.  Of course integrity has to be maintained.

Comment: you should at least tell us what you want to insert and into what tables....

Comment: show us some data before and after as well as the SQL code that is behind `Query1`